# Highcharts: how to assign different colours to a spline depending on positive or negative slope?

Tags: highcharts

I'm evaluating Highcharts for a project and it seems to be missing a built-in feature I would need.

For a spline, I need to assign one colour if the slope is positive, and another if it is negative, like this:

[image]

Before I invest the time in learning the API, it would be helpful to know if this is doable. A working example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamically calculated zones, for example:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    let points = this.series[0].points,
      zones = [],
      color;

    function addZone(value, color) {
      zones.push({
        value: value,
        color: color
      });
    }

    points.forEach(function(p, i) {
      if (points[i - 1]) {
        if (p.y >= points[i - 1].y) {

          if (color && color !== 'green') {
            addZone(points[i - 1].x, 'red');
          }

          color = 'green';

        } else if (p.y <= points[i - 1].y) {
          if (color && color !== 'red') {
            addZone(points[i - 1].x, 'green');
          }

          color = 'red';
        }
      }

      addZone(p.x, color);
    });

    this.series[0].update({
      zones: zones
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jmckag4q/1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones

Comment: Exactly what I was after. You've saved me many hours of struggle - much appreciated!

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work on a chart where I was overlaying the spline series over a candlestick series.

For reasons I don't pretend to understand, it only works if the spline series is above the candlestick series in the series array. If the candlestick series comes first, it runs without error but the colours aren't applied. 

https://jsfiddle.net/scotpip/3fmvkx2o/8/

This is workable, but I'd prefer to understand what's going on. Can anyone explain?

Comment: This works for smaller data sets, but for a data set of 80k candlesticks overlaid with the spline, the page freezes before completion, even on a powerful workstation. Seems that it's just too resource hungry for bigger charts.

Comment: Hi @Tullochgorum, All works if you correctly refer to the series in `load` event: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/173cy5jh/ Please check this plugin for performance tests: https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/33/Multicolor%20series

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek. I'm bemused as to why the load event wasn't working for me, as I was obviously changing the indexes as you suggest. I guess something went wrong with my build? I'm new to Visual Studio...

Comment: I don't see your code so I don't know. If you have any questions please reproduce the problem online.

Comment: Thanks - it was a hypothetical question as the code is now working.